# list need double click to toggle a class

Tags: jquery, css

Refer at this Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/7Yag9/2/**

Why if I click on the row nothing happen?

I need to double click to highlight the element.

It works only if I click on the select on the right.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove this line of CSS, it only takes one click :)

```
label{color:#777;padding-top:2px;display:block;}
```

The fiddle is updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ENtk8/1/).

In fact, you can leave the line in, but just remove the `display:block;` and it works.

EDIT: You can also just take out the `<label>` and `</label>` tags and put your CSS on the `<span>` or change the `<span>text</span>` to `<label>text</label>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `$`:

```
$(function() {
```

Wrapping `select` tags with `label` is not *valid*:

change these:

```
   <li>
        <label>
            <span>text</span>
            <select>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </li>
```

to:

```
    <li>
        <label>text</label>
            <select>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
    </li>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yag9/17/)

Comment: The demo fiddle didn't stick - it still goes to the original code :)

Comment: @Nick No it doesn't I have only chnaged first li tag's contents.

Comment: If that's the case, the `click` problem the OP raised doesn't seem to be solved... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you click the `li`, the `click` event of `select` is also fired. The first click applies the class but the second click event of `select` (which in turn bubbles to the `li` click event) removes the class. Adding `return false` on the select's `click` event does the job. I've updated the fiddle as well http://jsfiddle.net/7Yag9/9/.

```
$('li').on("click", function() {    
    $(this).toggleClass('sel');
});


$("select").on("click", function() {
    return false;
});​
```